# Error in opencart: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')'

Tags: php, opencart

I have an error in this opencart 1.5.6.4 script

> "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')' "

the script is like this:

```
 'title' => explode('-', $this->config->get('rumahkaosbintang_city'))[0] . ' - ' . $tujuan[0]. ' (' . $weight / 1000 . ' Kgram)' ,
```

could you tell me what is wrong with it?

Comment: Error is somewhere else

Comment: can you post the entire array?

Answer (score 0):

PHP can directly access an element from a function returned array (like `explode('-', value)[0]`) only since version 5.4.

Please check your PHP version, and upgrade it if it's lower, or otherwise use different syntax.
For example, to get the Nth element of a function returned array, before 5.4 you could do:

```
$NthArrayElement = array_slice(returningArrayFunction(), N - 1, 1);
```

And, in your use case:

```
$firstArrayElement = array_slice($this->config->get('rumahkaosbintang_city'), 0, 1);
$title => explode('-', $firstArrayElement . ' - ' . $tujuan[0]. ' (' . $weight / 1000 . ' Kgram)' ,
```